# isAnnotationPresent returning false after getBeansWithAnnotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am defining a custom annotation in a custom library

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {
      "com.***",
      ....
    })
public @interface EnableFoo {
  String[] urls();
}
```

the client (which has the library as dependency) would call it like this

```
@EnableFoo(
    urls = { "some-url", ... })
```

I want to get the parameter `urls` of my annotation so I use this code

```
  private List<String> initFoo() {

    var beans = ctx.getBeansWithAnnotation(EnableFoo.class);

    if (beans.size() != 1) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(
          "Multiple '@" + EnableFoo.class.getName() + "' declarations !");
    }

    Object bean = beans.values().iterator().next();

    Class<?> clazz = bean.getClass();
    if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(EnableFoo.class)) { // <--- return false !!
         String[] annotationUrls = clazz.getAnnotation(EnableFoo.class).urls();
         ....
    }
  }
```

the problem is that `isAnnotationPresent` return false even though just before there `ctx.getBeansWithAnnotation(EnableFoo.class)`

Can somebody explain me this weird behavior and if it is the right approach

**Edit 1**
I update my code to use `AnnotationUtils` but the annotation is always null

```
var annotation =
    AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(
        AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(bean),
        EnableFoo.class);
```

and here is my object `bean` at debug

[image]

**Answer**

thanks to @M. Deinum comment the solution was to use `findAnnotation` instead of `getAnnotation`

```
var annotation =
    AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(
        bean.getClass(), EnableFoo.class)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't know what to provide exactly, because i have some sensitive information

Comment: We'll have to see something representative of your actual code. Spring has some quirks that could explain this.

Comment: Can you try to setup a minimal project with Spring Boot that just contains the stuff that doesn't work for you? (could be an "empty" bean without any logic and something else that checks that annotation) If you cannot reproduce the situation, try to add more configs until you can reproduce - and at that time you probably will not need our help anymore ;-)

Comment: Don't do the check as you most likely will have a proxy which doesn't have the annotation. Instead use the `AnnotationUtils` to get the annotations from the class, which will properly unwrap the proxy for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum I made some updates with `AnnotationUtils` and `AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass` but still the same issue

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I made some updates

Comment: You don't need `AopProxyUtils` the annotaiton utils will do the unrwapping/scanning for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah but it didn't work

Comment: You should also be using `findAnnotation` and not `getAnnotation` afaik. Another otion is to in the class that is processing this, implement the `ImportAware` interface and get the metadata handled. You can checkout the various implementation in Spring itself how they obtain the annotation metadata.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum it work now, the trick was to use `findAnnotation` and not `getAnnotation`

Comment: @M.Deinum  Can you put the solution in answer section and accept the solution. So others would be able to find the question solution easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
private List<String> initFoo() {

    var beans = ctx.getBeansWithAnnotation(EnableFoo.class);

    if (beans.size() != 1) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(
          "Multiple '@" + EnableFoo.class.getName() + "' declarations !");
    }

    Object bean = beans.values().iterator().next();

    Class<?> clazz = bean.getClass();
    if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(EnableFoo.class)) { // <--- return false !!
         String[] annotationUrls = clazz.getAnnotation(EnableFoo.class).urls();
         ....
    }
  }
```

The problem with this is that `bean.getClass` will return not the actual class but a proxy. Depending on the type of proxy and type of annotation it might or might not be detected.

Spring itself ships with some nice utility classes which know about proxies and which can help to obtain annotations (or the metadata). One of those is [`AnnotationUtils`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html). Use this to obtain the annotation from the class. To do this you will need the `findAnnotation` as that will traverse the hierarchy of the class to find the annotation.

```java
private List<String> initFoo() {

    var beans = ctx.getBeansWithAnnotation(EnableFoo.class);

    if (beans.size() != 1) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(
          "Multiple '@" + EnableFoo.class.getName() + "' declarations !");
    }

    Object bean = beans.values().iterator().next();
    Class<?> clazz = bean.getClass();
    String[] annotationUrls = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(clazz, EnableFoo.class).urls();
    ....
}
```

This should find the annotation and return the values you want.